# Laravel 9 throw custom error view if DB connection fails?

Tags: laravel, database, error-handling, laravel-blade, laravel-9

what i am trying to do is if the connection to the database fails, instead of getting `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`, i want to throw a custom view that displays a simple h1 with the text that the connection fails. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given at the top, but i made it work with some modifications.

```
use Throwable;
use PDOException;

public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof PDOException) {
        return response()->view('errors.database', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by modifying your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` to catch that specific error:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception) {
    if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
        return response()->view('errorpage');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Of course you can change the `QueryException` to any exception that you want to handle, such as: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` or any other.

Answer (score 1):

In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
use PDOException;
use App\Exceptions\Handler;

class ExceptionHandler extends Handler
{
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof PDOException) {
            return response()->view('errors.database', [], 500);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

In `resources/views/errors`, `errors.database`, you can create custom style

Comment: In my situation i didn't need use App\Exceptions\Handler, and instead of using Exception i used Throwable

Comment: @Raitiko Actually, I don't know the complete workaround, So I suggested what we commonly do. :)